# Commas before and after 'too'

Tags: punctuation

I am always hesitating in writing to put commas before and after ***too***, because it sort of encumbers the sentence or unnecessarily interrupts the course of meaning, at least in my eyes. Should it always be used between commas or is there a rule with exceptions that can guide me?

For example, I have no problem of putting a comma before 'too' when it ends a sentence:

> She did not only buy apples but oranges, too.

But if 'too' is in the middle, that's where my hesitations begin:

> His desire is to make sure that the law is applied in our district so that ***we, too,*** (or ***we too***) may be protected.

Comment: More often than not _To put or to not put a comma there_  is a matter or style, rather than an issue of grammar. So while in your first case a pause is sort of necessitated (not really, though!), it's purely optional in your second sentence. Like with other parenthetical elements set off by commas, _too_ is a surplus word there and merely added to provide extra information.

Comment: In formal or academic writing, it's more appropriate that you add commas, but in fiction writing, it's your personal preference.